# How can I generate an SQL where clause from a filtered list of lines in a file?

Tags: sql, perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use Regexp::Common qw/net/;

getstore("https://<redacted>", "ips.txt");

open(my $input, "<", "ips.txt");

while (<$input>) {

print $1, "\n" if /($RE{net}{IPv4})/;

}
```

Hello all,

I've created a perl script above that will pull down IP addresses from a website using the API (redacted), and store the IP addresses in a text file. The  text file looks like this (but with many more IP addresses):

```
1.55.227.59
5.1.80.127 
5.1.80.235
```

I am attempting to figure out how to add a line to make the script print an output to look like this for all IP addresses in the file:

("1.55.227.59" OR "5.1.80.127" OR "5.1.80.235")

So far, attempts have been unsuccessful. Anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this question is about creating what appears to be part of an SQL where clause and really has nothing to do with regular expressions.

Comment: If this is really about creating SQL, then please see http://bobby-tables.com/ before doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Regexp::Common qw/net/;

print '(', join(' OR ', map { chomp; qq{"$_"} } grep { /$RE{net}{IPv4}/ } <DATA>), ")\n";

__DATA__
1.55.227.59
5.1.80.127
5.1.80.235
```

Output:

```
("1.55.227.59" OR "5.1.80.127" OR "5.1.80.235")
```

Comment: Hello Matt. Thanks very much for your help. Is there any way to combine the two in order to the direct the IP addresses to the print you've demonstrated? Right now I have it in two separate perl scripts. One to create the file spamhaus.txt (IP addresses), and one to read the spamhaus.txt file to produce the desired output (your script).

Comment: I'd like to use the output from my script to be read by your script.

Comment: @CodingNovice So, you don't care about the intermediate .txt file at all?

Comment: The goal is to get the output as you had it at the end. The file creation is unnecessary, that's just the only way I figured out how to do it at this point by redirecting the IP addresses the initial script pulls from the API to a text file, then using that file in the <DATA> section.

Comment: I'm sorry, there's a piece missing from my script above. Initially, it pulls the file from the API, then stores the text. I fixed it to show what the script really does, save for the API which has credentials.

Comment: @CodingNovice You can use `get()` instead of `getstore()` and split on `\n`. I'm not in front of a computer right now, but give that a shot.